# Двумерные массивы - Поменять местами столбцы с минимальной и максимальной суммой элементов

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

Помогите пожалуйста новичку с задачей. Проблема заключается в том, что у меня не получается определить **минимумы** и **максимумы** для столбца. Я упускаю что-то очевидное из-за чего не могу продвинуться дальше к решению непосредственно на замену максимума и минимума. Если запустить код, то максимум обозначается **верно**, но минимум считывает первое число и на этом все. Что тут не так? Стоит так же добавить, что я перепробовал очень много всего, ставил условия, менял обозначения мин макс между внутренними и внешними циклами и другое, в лучшем случае максимум по столбику есть.

**Задача:** Поменять местами столбцы с **минимальной** и **максимальной** суммой элементов.

**Входные данные:**
Два натуральных числа NN и MM. Далее с новой строки NN строк по MM целых чисел в каждой. NN и MM не превышают десяти.

**Выходные данные:**
Вывести исходную матрицу NN на MM, в которой столбцы с минимальной и максимальной суммой элементов поменяны местами. Числа разделять пробелами. Если присутствует несколько столбцов с одинаковой минимальной суммой элементов, то использовать первый по порядку. Аналогично с максимальной суммой.

Sample Input:

```
3 4
1 2 3 4
1 3 4 5
0 2 3 -2
```

Sample Output:

```
3 2 1 4
4 3 1 5
3 2 0 -2
```

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int N, M, count = 0, max = -9999, min = 9999, jmin, jmax;
scanf("%d%d", &N, &M);
int arr[N][M];
int k = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
         scanf("%d ", &arr[i][j]);
     }
 } 

for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        
     if (i == k) {
         count = count + arr[j][i];
     }
     if (max <= count) {
         max = count;
         jmax = j; 
     }
     if (min >= count) {
         min = count; 
         jmin = j;
     }
 } 
    
 printf("%d ", count);
 count = 0;
 k++;
 }  

  printf("\n%d ", max);
  printf("%d \n", min);


for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
   for(int j = 0; j < M; j++) { 
        if (j == jmax) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        } 
        else if (j == jmin) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        } 
        else {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
     } 
    printf("\n");
  } 

return 0;
}
```

Буду крайне благодарен услышать ваши советы и помощь!

Comment: Крайне рекомендую вместо `M` и `N` использовать имена `Lines` и `Columns` (вы сразу начнете лучше ориентироваться в том, что именно перебираете в данном цикле). Далее, попробуйте после ввода данных продолжить как-то так -- `int sum, minsum, maxsum, min_col, max_col;    for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++) { sum = 0;      for (int i = 0; i < Lines; i++)  sum += arr[i][j];` (Т.е. вам надо для каждого столбца перебирать все индексы строк) / *Надеюсь, далее вы сами сообразите как искать минимальную и максимальную суммы и запоминать соответствующие им индексы столбцов*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, я [немного причесал](https://ideone.com/vrzZoH) ваш код, посмотрите...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int N, M;
    scanf("%d%d", &N, &M);

    // Мой VC++ VLA не поддерживает...
    int ** arr = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        arr[i] = malloc(M*sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
    }

    // Первоначальные минимум и максимум берем для первого столбца,
    // а не какие-то 9999 и -9999...
    int idxMin = 0, idxMax = 0, min =  0, max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        min += arr[i][0];
    max = min;

    for(int i = 1; i < M; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) sum += arr[j][i];
        if (max < sum)
        {
            max = sum;
            idxMax = i;
        }
        if (min > sum)
        {
            min = sum;
            idxMin = i;
        }
    }

    // printf("\n%d %d\n", max, min); Это не требуется

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int tmp = arr[i][idxMin];
        arr[i][idxMin] = arr[i][idxMax];
        arr[i][idxMax] = tmp;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```